# Removing NULL with COALESCE in Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have some dynamic SQL as part of a stored procedure I want to execute:

```
    SET @SQL_TXT = 'INSERT INTO ' +@ENTY_TABLE_NAME+
              '([ITEM_NAME]
               ,[ADD_DTT]
               ,[ADD_USR]
               ,[UPD_DTT]
               ,[UPD_USR]
               ,[ACTIVE_IND]
               ,[ITEM_PK])
         VALUES 
               ('''+@UPD_VALUE+'''
          , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
          , '''+@UPD_USR_DOM_NAME+''', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'''+@UPD_USR_DOM_NAME+''',''Y'','''+@ITEM_PK+''');
          SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
          RETURN;'
```

This runs fine, but ITEM_NAME can't be NULL so I want to ad a COALESE():

```
SET @SQL_TXT = 'INSERT INTO ' +@ENTY_TABLE_NAME+
          '(COALESCE([ITEM_NAME], '')
           ,[ADD_DTT]
           ,[ADD_USR]
           ,[UPD_DTT]
           ,[UPD_USR]
           ,[ACTIVE_IND]
           ,[ITEM_PK])
     VALUES 
           ('''+@UPD_VALUE+'''
      , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
      , '''+@UPD_USR_DOM_NAME+''', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'''+@UPD_USR_DOM_NAME+''',''Y'','''+@ITEM_PK+''');
      SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
      RETURN;'
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'COALESCE'.

Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ');

              SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

              RETURN;'.

Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

For the life of me I don't see where this ')' is. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: here is the exec

```
EXECUTE SP_executesql @SQL_TXT, N'@Id INTEGER OUTPUT', @Id OUTPUT
```

Comment: in dynamic sql, 2 single quotes = 1 single quote.  So after converting, this reads: (coalesce([item_name],')     .....   try adding another set of '':    '(coalesce([item_name], '''')

Comment: @OK,. I see and and that makes sense. I am still getting:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'COALESCE'. Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know SQL Server at all. Maybe you need a space before coalesce?  so maybe try    ' <blank space> (coalesce[item_name], '''')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not put `coalesce()` around the column name destination of your `insert`, you use it around the value being inserted.

```
  SET @SQL_TXT = 'INSERT INTO ' +@ENTY_TABLE_NAME+
              '([ITEM_NAME]
               ,[ADD_DTT]
               ,[ADD_USR]
               ,[UPD_DTT]
               ,[UPD_USR]
               ,[ACTIVE_IND]
               ,[ITEM_PK])
         VALUES 
               ('''+coalesce(@UPD_VALUE,'')+'''
          , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
          , '''+@UPD_USR_DOM_NAME+''', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'''+@UPD_USR_DOM_NAME+''',''Y'','''+@ITEM_PK+''');
          SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
          RETURN;'
```

---

Note: `@UPD_USR_DOM_NAME` is inserted into two different columns. Not sure if that is intentional, just thought I would point it out.

You can also fully parameterize the rest of your values for use with [**`sp_executesql`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) instead of concatenating them like that. (Guessing at the data types of your parameters in this example)

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
declare @params nvarchar(max);
declare @id int;

set @sql = N'INSERT INTO ' +@ENTY_TABLE_NAME+'([ITEM_NAME] ,[ADD_DTT] ,[ADD_USR] ,[UPD_DTT] ,[UPD_USR] ,[ACTIVE_IND] ,[ITEM_PK])
      VALUES (coalesce(@UPD_VALUE,''), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @UPD_USR_DOM_NAME, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,@UPD_USR_DOM_NAME,''Y'',@ITEM_PK);
      SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
      RETURN;'

set @params = N'@UPD_VALUE varchar(32),@UPD_USR_DOM_NAME varchar(32), @ITEM_PK varchar(32), @Id INTEGER OUTPUT';

EXECUTE SP_executesql @sql, @params, @UPD_Value, @UPD_USER_DOM_NAME, @ITEM_PK, @Id = @Id OUTPUT;
```

dynamic sql reference:

- [The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)
- [**`sp_executesql`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)